# Can I host webhook for my lex bot on my own server instead of AWS Lambda?

Tags: aws-lex

Seems like AWS Lex supports using AWS Lambda for hosting my application logic. Can I provide my own custom webhook instead of using AWS Lambda?

I would like to host my own server and use it to handle the webhook requests.

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently possible, Lex can only integrate with Lambda functions to run some back-end logic.

If you have to run code off your own server, you could make a request to the server from the Lambda function to fetch the response and then return it back to Lex. However, if you want to do this to minimize Lambda associated costs, this wouldn't help.